# Getting results via eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, relation, eloquent

Hi I have a table in my database which contains a column with integer values which are actually the primary key of another tabel 
**Table 1: Details**

```
column : subjects
value : 12,10,1,50,89,88
```

And another table is **subject** from where I should fetch the result. I want to know if I can fetch them using my model instead of repeating my code in controller everytime I need to fetch them. 
I know you can define relations using
`$this->belongsTo()` 
Or `hasMany()` depending on circumstances. I want to see If I can use this using scope on Model. 
The final result I am looking for is json data returned from table **Subject**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) for this rather than the way you are comma delimiting in a single database table field.

You will have a new record for each association which may seem bad to you at first but it really is worthwhile, work with Eloquent so you don't need to add custom logic to explode those id's and associate manually.

```
students
    id - integer
    name - string

subjects
    id - integer
    name - string
    subjectable_id - integer
    subjectable_type - string
```

Then in your models something like this

```
class Subject extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning subjectable models.
     */
    public function subjectable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Student extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the post's comments.
     */
    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Subject', 'subjectable');
    }
}
```

You can then attach subjects to many different models the same way I demonstrated it attached to Students here.

**Edit**: If you would like to keep with your same interpretation of how this data is used, you could potentially do this in the Model but it's difficult to say without seeing the logic you are trying not to repeat.